# Direct2D Errors- d2d1_1.h is filled with errors

Tags: c++, direct2d

I was working with Direct2D for a few months, then got started on Direct3D for about 3 weeks. I need to start a program I was using before, but now the d2d1_1.h file won't compile. It is FILLED with errors- 1019 errors to be exact, and I don't know what to do. I had to install a different version of directx for me to be able to use direct3d (the SDK for it), but the file itself hasn't changed- I have the file backed up and they are exactly the same. Here's a sample of the errors:

> identifier "D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE_DEFINITION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR" is undefined  EvoAI   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\d2d1_1.h 298
>
> identifier "D2D_MATRIX_4X4_F" is undefined EvoAI   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\d2d1_1.h 588

The linker properties are the same as before, I think. They were changed from the base linker file from before when I switched over to 3D, but I updated the properties to the previous ones.

I will be checking the question every few minutes if more info is needed.

What is the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

For those who have the same issue as I, try switching to x64. Turns out I didn't have x86 stuff installed. Hope it solves your issue too!